# Setting up dual monitors in Ubuntu (my laptop and one external monitor)

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am new to Ubuntu. I am trying to connect an external monitor to my laptop.

I have looked at many forums and the solutions do not work for me or are not simple enough for me to follow.

When I try to add another monitor by choosing System > Preferences > Monitors I only see one pink monitor screen labelled as "unknown".

Some websites suggested loading nvidia driver.  I have tried the command nvidia-settings and now when I try System > Preferences > Monitors I get an alert that says "It appears that your graphics driver does not support the necessary extensions to this tool.  Do you want to use your graphics driver vendor's tool instead?

Clicking Yes goes to a window labelled NVIDIA X Server settings and an alert says "You do not appear to be using the Nvidia X driver.  Please edit your X configuration file (just run nvidia-xconfig as root and restart the X server.

Clicking No goes to the Monitor Preferences window displaying the pink unknown monitor.

All help appreciated (nothing would be too basic for me!)
Mel

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Seth This has an upvoted answer that appears *might* have solved the problem here ...and if it didn't, it may help others with similar situations. (Since it's upvoted, this doesn't even appear in the list of unanswered questions.) Why are we closing this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a nvidia graphics card? Then you can try running the following command from the console

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Then restart. Then you may configure dual monitors from "NVIDIA X Server settings".

Hope this helps.